# CakePHP Error: Unable to configure the session, setting session.use_trans_sid failed

Tags: php, session, cakephp, session-variables

I am using `Cake 2.6`, `PHP 5.5` (but i tried 5.6, 5.3)
After moving my site from localhost to FTP server, I am getting an error from CakePHP

> Unable to configure the session, setting session.use_trans_sid failed.

The Strange is that error occured even when I turn on a `use_trans_sid` variable. 
What else I have to do to site works fine?

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that I can enable or disable session.use_trans_sid, still getting same error.

Comment line 589 in `lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/CakeSession.php` where initialize session.use_trans_sid to 0, solve the problem.